# Why does the fan stop after opening gnome-system-monitor?

Tags: fan, temperature

I have recently noticed a very strange effect when working in Ubuntu 13.10. I've always had a loud fan and I found it very irritating. It turns on loud even when the system temperature is relatively low. To try to fix this, I tried to control the fan speeds through lm-sensors but I don't think my fans have that capability because it completely ignored them.

However, I have recently stumbled upon a way to stop the fans from working, by opening gnome-system-monitor. Every time the fan is running on loud and it shouldn't be I just open gnome-system-monitor and it fixes it. Does anyone know why this is happening?